# Generate the n-th letter of the alphabet in a tikz loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

The following code draws 10 nodes, labelled from 0 to 9.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,9}{
            \node (i) at (\i, \i) {\i} ;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead, I would like the nodes to be labelled from `a` to `j`.

Is there a function which, given an integer n, returns the n-th letter of the alphabet? I would like my loop to be as follows:

```
\foreach \i in {0,...,9}{
    \node (i) at (\i, \i) {\someMagicalFunction{\i}} ;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach [count=\i] \j in {a,b,...,j}{
            \node (\i) at (\i, \i) {\j} ;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

percusse mentions the `alphalph` package in a comment, and its `\alphalph` does exactly what you want. Note that `\alphalph{0}` creates no output.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,100}{
            \node (\i) at (\i, \i) {\alphalph{\i}} ;
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe add the `alphalph` package from Heiko for converting more complicated cases?

Comment: Thanks, I used `alphalph` which is the easiest to read.

Answer (score 10):

This would be my first try, using a counter (no need of additional packages):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{cnti}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,9}{
            \setcounter{cnti}{\i}\addtocounter{cnti}{1}
            \node (i) at (\i, \i) {\alph{cnti}} ;
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also your counter value is limited to 25 ;)

Comment: @percusse yes, I see. I just fired `texdoc alphalph` --- thanks!

Comment: Your answer produces an output which is exactly what I want. However, the code is not very nice to read, since we have to create a counter. This is why I accepted @torbjørn-t's answer with `alphalph` function.